# How to prevent duplicate records to be entered on database?

Tags: vb.net

Here is a part in my code on Visual Basic.
When I try to input a record which is already present in the database, the program should prompt me that there is a duplicate...

HERE IS MY CODE:

Program adds records

```
             recSet.Open("SELECT * FROM Prod ", connection, 3, 3)
             recSet.AddNew()
             recSet.Fields("prodSKU").Value = prodSKU.Text
             recSet.Fields("prodName").Value = prodName.Text
             recSet.Fields("prodSRP").Value = prodSRP.Text
             recSet.Fields("prodDesc").Value = prodDesc.Tex 
             recSet.Fields("prodUnit").Value = comboUnit.Text
             recSet.Fields("ClassDisc").Value = classDisc.Text
             recSet.Fields("ProdCateg").Value = comboCtgry.Text

                recSet.Update()
                recSet.Close()
                MsgBox("Records added succesful!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success!")
                'COMOB BOXES'
                comboUnit.Items.Clear()
                comboCtgry.Items.Clear()

                recSet.Open("SELECT DISTINCT prodUnit from Prod", connection, 3, 3)
                Do While Not recSet.EOF
                    comboUnit.Items.Add(recSet.Fields("prodUnit").Value)
                    recSet.MoveNext()
                Loop
                recSet.Close()
                recSet.Open("SELECT DISTINCT prodCateg from Prod", connection, 3, 3)
                Do While Not recSet.EOF
                    comboCtgry.Items.Add(recSet.Fields("prodCateg").Value)
                    recSet.MoveNext()
                Loop
                recSet.Close()

                prodSKU.Text = ""
                prodName.Text = ""
                prodSRP.Text = ""
                prodDesc.Text = ""
                classDisc.Text = ""
                comboCtgry.Text = ""
                comboUnit.Text = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer updated as the previous answer was for SQL Database but @DatNoobPotatoPCGuy said his Database is MS Access database).

```
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection()
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
Dim numberOfRecords as Int = 0;
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=pathToDatabase"
con.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select count(*) From Prod where prodSKU = @prodSKU AND prodName = @prodName AND prodSRP = @prodSRP AND prodDesc = @prodDesc AND prodUnit = @prodUnit AND ClassDisc = @ClassDisc AND ProdCateg = @ProdCateg", con)
With cmd
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodSKU", prodSKU.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", prodName.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodSRP", prodSRP.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodDesc", prodDesc.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodUnit", comboUnit.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassDisc", classDisc.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdCateg", comboCtgry.Text)
End With
numberOfRecords = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
If numberOfRecords <> 0 Then
   MsgBox("Row(s) in database with following data are already exist!",MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Are you trying to insert same record?")
   Exit Sub
Else
   'Your code to insert data
End If
```

Try this code and please let us know your result.

Comment: Dragged the Table to the ProdD.dbml keeps on telling me that the file is unsupported... using MS Access 2007 and MS Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @DatNoobPotatoPCGuy Oh! I used this method using `Service-based Database` directly from Visual Studio but since you are using MS Access database so maybe that is creating the error **"Unsupported!"** BTW I will try to get more information about this to you if you don't solve it till then, now little busy! :)

Comment: Okay, I am editing My answer and you check whether it works for you or helps you and let me know...

Comment: Thank you very much i will try coding this later when I get to school :)

Comment: @DatNoobPotatoPCGuy Its Ok!, you are welcome. Hope you solve your issue! :)

Comment: Oh by the way I forgot...is there a way to use the 'recordset.Update()' to replace the data on the duplicate record?

Comment: Yaaaaaaaaaaaaa!!!!!!!!!! I am really very happy you solved it <3 its like I accomplished one of my biggest goal :) :P 
And for your second Question would you like to create a new question....? :)

Comment: Just a follow up :3 Forgot to ask that one though

Comment: You can try this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qN3GyEa-efU and let me know if there's any prob. ?